# Regex to replace every character with another character EXCEPT for what's in square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, character, brackets

Hi I need help with a regex.. if it's possible I'm not sure..

input String: `Will you [B] meet me [A] in the [E] end`

I want all the character that are not inside [] brackets to be replaced by some other character; let's say a period. And the [] brackets are also replaced by the same character.

so desired output: `..........B...........A..........E.....`

another example: `[A]red[B]elephant[C]hello[D]`
output: `.A.....B..........C.......D.`

I tried to explain best I can if anyone can help that'd be great.

thanks.

Comment: Where there ever be multiple characters inside the square brackets?

Comment: sorry yes there may be multiple characters

Comment: `string.replace(/[^\]](?![^\[]*\])/g, '.')`

Comment: @Sam you could provide it as an answer.

Comment: @Roman why you delete the current question? It's totally different from this question. My opinion is, you should accept vks answer and move on to the next question if a further doubts. Or ask it to the below answerers.

Comment: @Roman If you change your question considerably, previous answer will confuse future visitors. Therefore, I have rolled back this question, and I suggest undeleting your new question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/26002694/1529630)

Answer (score 5):

```
.(?![^\[]*\])|\[
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/1

Comment: Good work! In Javascript: `'abc[foo]red[bar]123'.replace(/.(?![^\[]*\])|\[/g, '.')`;

Answer (score 2):

or this pattern
`([^][]+(?=\]))*.` and replace w/ `$1.`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sW9xU4/17)

Answer (score 2):

You could split on brackets, then replace characters in every other element:

```
function replace(str, rep) {
    return str.split(/\[|]/).map(function(seg, i) {
        return i % 2 ? seg : seg.replace(/./g, rep);
    }).join(rep);
}

> replace("Will you [B] meet me [A] in the [E] end", '.')
          "..........B...........A..........E....."

> replace("[A]red[Bm]elephant[Cm]hello[D]", '.')
          ".A.....Bm..........Cm.......D."
```

This solution might be more extensible if you wanted to, for example, support additional kinds of brackets, such as `{}`, wanted to somehow transform the text inside the brackets, etc.

The solution below tries to capture the notion of "outside brackets", with a simpler (?) regexp meaning "everything between a right bracket (or start of string) and a left bracket (or end of string)":

```
function replace(str, rep) {
    return str.replace(/(^|]).*?(\[|$)/g, function(match) { 
        return match.replace(/./g, rep); 
    });
 }
```